# CakePHP "Object not found!" XAMP

Tags: cakephp

I have downloaded and setup CakePHP on XAMP (Win 7) following by http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQos_O-nqtQ tutorial.

When I setup new project using NetBeans IDE 8.0.1, everything goes fine but when I tried to view page of my ItemsController's "index" function using http:// myproject/items/ it says: "Object not found!".

[image]

I tried "http:// myproject/index.php/items/" and my page loads without javascript and css files. I tried everything which are suggested [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html), but could not resolve the issue after spending many hours. Does anyone know the exact solution of this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might need to enable mod_rewrite on XAMP.  See here:  http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/

Comment: Thanks Kai, the problem was solved from the link you provided. The problem solved after one change in httpd.conf file residing in xampp\apache\conf folder. Change: *AllowOverride none* to *AllowOverride All*.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved from the link provided by Kai  [leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp](http://leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp). The problem solved after one change in httpd.conf file residing in xampp\apache\conf folder. Change: AllowOverride none to AllowOverride All.

@Kai: Thanks a lot.

*I have to post my own answer as Kai did not post his reply as "Answer" even after a long time*